# how to create "send email" button on your own google maps website

Tags: email, maps

Hi everybody :) I have a problem. I would like to make it so that when I enter the address. Click on "Send Email" button to send me an email with "http: //" in the form of a link which opens after pressing the Navigator Maps. My code is here.

`<?php`
`echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>`
`<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' dir='ltr' lang='en-us' xml:lang='en-us'>`
`<head>`
    `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />`
    `<meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='en-us' />`
    `<link rel='icon' type='image/gif' href='http://www.nsc.ee/rssimg/favicon.png' />`
    `<link rel='stylesheet' href='contact.css' type='text/css' />`
    `<link rel='stylesheet' href='info.css' type='text/css' />`
`<script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places'>`
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'>`</script>`
`<script src='js/jquery.geocomplete.js'></script>`
`<script>`
$(function(){
    `$('#geocomplete').geocomplete({`
map: '.map_canvas',
    `details: 'form ',`
markerOptions: {
    `draggable: true`
 }
   `});`
`$('#geocomplete').bind('geocode:dragged', function(event, latLng){`
`$('input[name=lat]').val(latLng.lat());`
`$('input[name=lng]').val(latLng.lng());`
`$('#reset').show();`
`});`
`$('#reset').click(function(){`
`$('#geocomplete').geocomplete('resetMarker');`
`$('#reset').hide();`
`return false;`
`});`
`$('#find').click(function(){`
`$('#geocomplete').trigger('geocode');`
`}).click();`
`});`
`</script>`

`<script>";`

`echo"`
`<form>`
`<table border='0' bgcolor='#1c1a1a'>`
`<tr>`
`<td align='center'><input id='geocomplete' type='text' size='48px' placeholder='Palun sisestage aadress' value='' /><form>`
`<label><font color=#FFFFFF>Pikkus:</font></label>`
`<input name='lng' type='text' size='20px' value=''>`
`<label><font color=#FFFFFF>Laius:</font></label>`
`<input name='lat' type='text' size='20px' value=''>`
`<a id='reset' href='#' style='display:none;'></a>`
`</form></td></tr></table>`

`<table border='0' bgcolor='#1c1a1a'>`
`<tr>`
`<td align='center'><div class='map_canvas'></div></td></tr></table></p>`
`</form>";`
`?>`

Comment: And what is your question ? If you don't have a clue about how to do it, I would suggest hiring someone to do it for you. if you have an idea how to start but are stuck, show us your efforts and explain where exactly you're stuck...

Comment: Check out the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to read about properly formatting your posts.

Comment: My question: How can i create worked "send email" button on my google map? When i push "send email" button, send emails specific email address containing http:// map link.

Comment: HERE is my test page [link](http://www.nsc.ee/test.php) I entered address and this address sended to my email automatically, when i push a "send email" button. That i want :)